# When declaring a mixin in Ember.js, what does it mean to take the application namespace as the first parameter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am browsing through Flamejs' source code and am seeing this a lot:

```
Flame = Ember.Application.create()
```

declaring mixin:

```
Ember.mixin(Flame, { ... } );
```

Is the application namespace passed in as the first param because an anonymous mixin is declared above? For example, if I were to rewrite it as a named mixin, would I say:

```
Flame.fooMix = Ember.mixin.create({ ... });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it. Ember.mixin() is a way to extend an ember object via another object. `Ember.mixin(A, B)` is adding the members from `B` into `A`